# OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from /home/XXXX/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyresparser/config.cfg

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am trying to extract data from CV using this tool [pyresparser](https://github.com/OmkarPathak/pyresparser) when I installed all the requirements and run my script I got this error.

**Code**

```
from pyresparser import ResumeParser
data = ResumeParser('cv.pdf').get_extracted_data()
```

**Output**

```
  File "C:\Users\AMJAD\Desktop\extract_data_from_cv\.env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 487, in load_model_from_path
    config = load_config(config_path, overrides=overrides)
  File "C:\Users\AMJAD\Desktop\extract_data_from_cv\.env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 650, in load_config
    raise IOError(Errors.E053.format(path=config_path, name="config file"))
OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from C:\Users\AMJAD\Desktop\extract_data_from_cv\.env\lib\site-packages\pyresparser\config.cfg
```

I am running this inside a venv with Python version 3.10.4, spaCy version 3.3.1, OS Windows 11, and Pipelines en_core_web_sm (3.3.0).

PS - I did the same steps on google colab and work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that only works with spaCy v2. What version of spaCy are you using in Colab?

Comment: Yes, I solve it by downgrading to v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, after being stuck with the same error for a while. It's a version issue:

`pip install nltk`

`pip install spacy==2.3.5`

`pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacymodels/releases/download/en_core_we_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz`

`pip install pyresparser`

does the trick. Also try different spacy versions and models, because they produce different results. Haven't tested any further myself. Hope this helps :)

Answer from [Quppi](https://github.com/OmkarPathak/pyresparser/issues/46#issuecomment-776139256)